# Pass multiple parsing values to addPositionalArgument function

Tags: c++, qt, qcommandlineparser

I was looking on [how to parse the command line arguments](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html). I found this:

```
// A boolean option with multiple names (-f, --force)
QCommandLineOption forceOption(QStringList() << "f" << "force",
        QCoreApplication::translate("main", "Overwrite existing files."));
parser.addOption(forceOption);
```

This works fine. But how can I add two values for a string value? For example, `foo --source ...` should be the same with `foo -s ...`.

I tried:

```
parser.addPositionalArgument(
   QStringList() << "s" << "source",
   QCoreApplication::translate("main", "...")
);
```

But this throws an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 
'QCommandLineParser::addPositionalArgument(QStringList&, QString)'
parser.addPositionalArgument(QStringList() << "t" << "title",
QCoreApplication::translate("main", "...."));
```

That's probably `addPositionalArgument` expects a  string instead of a string list.

But how can I alias two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use a positional argument for that. Positional arguments are arguments that need to appear in a specific order, and can have any value. They are no parameters introduced with something like `-s` or `--source`.

As you already found out, you can alias the two using a `QStringList` in [`QCommandLineOption`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineoption.html). If you want an argument to follow, just specify this in the constructor:

```
QCommandLineOption sourceOption(
    QStringList() << "s" << "source",
    "Specify the source", // better translate that string
    "source", // the name of the following argument
    "something" // the default value of the following argument, not required
);
parser.addOption(sourceOption);
```

Comment: And how can I differentiate between string and boolean?

Comment: @IonicăBizău You get a [`QVariant`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html) when accesing the argument so you can call `toBool` to get a boolean and `toString` to get a string. `type()` will return whether this is a bool or a string

Comment: I guess then I have to call `parser.addOption(sourceOption);`, right?

Comment: @IonicăBizău Yes, that need to be added after my code snippet